# Ionic Push using $http not working for android (Push Error Code 101)

Tags: android, ionic-framework

```
 push: function (tokens, message) {
      var privateKey = 'xxx';
      var appId = 'xxx';
      var auth = btoa(privateKey + ':');
      var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://push.ionic.io/api/v1/push',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-Ionic-Application-Id': appId,
          'Authorization': 'basic ' + auth
        },
        data: {
          "tokens": tokens,
          "notification": {
            "alert": message
          }
        }
      };

// Make the API call
      $http(req).success(function (resp) {
        // Handle success
        console.log(tokens);
        console.log(resp);
      }).error(function (error) {
        // Handle error
        console.log("Ionic Push: Push error...");
      });
    }
```

I am using the above code to push notifications. It gets into the 
success handler and prints the token used and message id, to the console. But when i check the status with the message id, its saying Push Error Code 101.

When i use the same token using Ionic.io website for one time notification screen, it works !
How can i make this working using angular code ?

Thanks !

Comment: Did you get it working? I have the exact same problem!

Comment: @barro32 Yes ! Make sure you are sending the tokens as arrays and not as an object. Once i did that push started working .